# Can we create lightning component to display dashboards?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Can anyone help in this requirement like I need to develop a component for the dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot build lightning components that can be used in dashboards as of now.

There exist an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lITwQAM) for its support. You can upvote it to prioritize it.

The workaround would be to create a custom dashboard page, but then you wont be able to add standard dashboard components